# ActiveReport space between sub-reports

Tags: activereports

I Have a report with **n** sub-reports, how do I remove the vertical space between two sub-reports?

Is the vertical space fixed by default?

P.S. `CanShrink` is set to *true* already.

Answer (score 0):

There're should be no space if there's no gap between Subreport controls. For troubleshooting this issue just "color" the content of subreports to see which one produces "vertical space".

If you provide a simplified sample (with no datasource) someone could provide you the solution.